# Custom pagination not working

Tags: magento-1.8

I had displayed images from my custom module database on modules template. and  applied pagination on it. on frontend it showing the pagination block but pagination is not working it shows all  images.

here is code of my  block file:-

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('brand/brand')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
```

and my phtml file code is:

```
<?php
$data = Mage::getModel('brand/brand')->getCollection();
$name =$data->getData('title');
$image = $data->getData('filename');
echo $this->getPagerHtml();
foreach ($data as $dt) 
{
    $name =$dt['title'];
    $image = $dt['filename'];



    echo $frontimage= '<img height="60px" width="80px" src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$image . '" />;
}



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem.
In the template you have this line:

```
$data = Mage::getModel('brand/brand')->getCollection();
```

then you iterate through the `$data` values.
In this case, the pagination does not affect your collection, because you are initializing your collection again.
Make your template file look like this:

```
$data = $this->getCollection();
echo $this->getPagerHtml();
foreach ($data as $dt) 
{
    $name =$dt['title'];
    $image = $dt['filename'];
    echo $frontimage= '<img height="60px" width="80px" src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$image . '" />;
}
```

This way you will use the collection initialized in the block and processed by the pager.